# Проблема с загрузкой js и css на IIS

Tags: iis, windows-8

Я установил Windows 8 и включил IIS, настроил сайт, но когда я запрашиваю страницу то javascript и css не грузятся...

В Visual Studio 2012 если запускать то всё работает...
Что может быть?

Answer (score 4):

Разобрался [вот тут](http://www.adilmughal.com/2011/11/iis-7-not-loading-css-and-image.html):

Была отключена поддержка Static Content в IIS. Ее можно включить в Control Panel / Turn Windows Features On or Off:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: эта галочка спасла меня после дня танца з бубнами на работе. Спс автору!